# How many Transaction types in NEAR?

Tags: nearprotocol

Can any one please help me on the transaction/operation types in Near where value/near is involved.I have seen multiple operation types like transfer , draw etc

Answer (score 2):

There are only 7 native action kinds in NEAR Protocol:

- Transfer (deposit gets transferred from a signer to a receiver account)
- CreateAccount
- DeleteAccount (the remaining funds on an account are transferred to the beneficiary account id)
- CallFunction (tokens can be deposited [attached] to the function call, e.g. `draw` method expects some tokens attached)
- AddKey
- DeleteKey

Comment: Thanks @Vlad Frolov  for helping me out . Can you please point me to documentation where you got this info and also does all these transaction types involve any value

Comment: There is no high-level documentation, I fear. The low-level reference is here https://nomicon.io/RuntimeSpec/Actions.html